Can't mock a Stream in WebSocketChannel in Dart: Error type 'null' is not a subtype of 'Stream<dynamic>'
I am tying to test my classes that use WebSocket connection. I made a mock from the class WebSocketChannel, but when i try to set the mocked response, it throws an exception "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Stream'" It does not matter if you put thenAnswer() or thenReturn() or if the list is empty or not. There is the code:
class MockWebSocketChannel extends Mock implements WebSocketChannel {} 
void main() { 
 setUp(() { 
   WebSocketChannel ws = MockWebSocketChannel(); 
   when(ws.stream).thenAnswer((_)=>Stream.fromIterable(List.empty())); //Error 
 } 
} 

I found a solution for this problem through the override of stream getter in the mock class:
class MockWebSocketChannel extends Mock implements WebSocketChannel {
    @override Stream<dynamic> get stream => Stream.fromIterable(response); 
} 

